# Extend view with RSpec.configure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I disabled ActionController's `include_all_helpers`, so I have to deal with this inside my view specs. This works fine:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "admin/test.html.haml" do
  before(:each) { view.extend Admin::BaseHelper }
  it { render }
end
```

I want to extract the before line to spec_helper.rb:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :view) do
    if example.metadata[:full_description].start_with?('admin/')
      view.extend Admin::BaseHelper
    end
  end
end
```

No my spec fails:

```
undefined method `view_context' for nil:NilClass
```

So my extend call leads to view being nil? Am I missing something? Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: it looks like this is a recent regression in rspec: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code seems to be fine and it seems to be a [bug in rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/833) or an related project. Thanks to phoet for the hint.